# Error in ANTLR4 generated Python code

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

Python (both 2/3) generated from ANTLR4 grammar results in the following lines of code in the grammar's parser python module:

```
self.state = 79
self.state()
```

As expected this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3):

The buggy code is a result of poor symbol choice in the ANTLR grammar. Since the generated python code uses the variable name `state` therefore if the grammar also contains the word `state` the generated code will have the above problem. The solution is to rename the term in your grammar.